# Session issue with vps

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, vps

I've registered `vps` host with `godaddy` and have some code with php `codeigniter`.

On shared host it works perfectly but when i transfer the code to the vps account the session makes problems as the information in session appears in some pages and some pages not.

Also if i store session value it will appear to all other users from different countries.
Any help

Comment: Ask godaddy, the shared host may be configured to start sessions automatically, covering where your code actually misses the call to session_start().

Comment: godaddy sucks with frameworks

Comment: What version of CodeIgniter ... and what version of PHP ??

Comment: @BrianGottier 
The last version of codeigniter 
I've tried php v5.6 and 7.0

Comment: @ArleighHix I tried to contact them but they told me it should be setup from my end cause they have restriction to do it.

Also if i miss session_start() it wouldn't explain why multiple users from different devices get the same session without even trying to store it.